# wso2 governance registry web portlet http access

Tags: wso2

I've read source code of wso2 greg, and find that there is a tomcat embedded in it, and there are two connectors: http with port 9763 and https with port 9443. But when I type the url [http://localhost:9763/carbon] in browser, it redirect to https automatically. While I can't find the related source code about the redirecting.
Can anybody help?
thx

Answer (score 0):

The Management Console (UI) of all WSO2 Carbon based products communicate with backend web service called AdminService. These services are secured and that's why it can be accessed only through https.

More info - http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2013/06/invoking-wso2-carbon-admin-services.html

Comment: I know that there are many AdminServices, but after I list all of them, I cant find the exact service that respond to the redirecting action